# Local User/Group permissions to add user, deny delete user

Tags: windows-server-2008

On Windows server 2008, is it possible to create a local group or a user with the permission to add other users but deny them the right to delete other users?  Using active directory is not an option for this.

If it is possible, how would I accomplish this?  I've been looking in the Local Group Policy Editor, but was unable to find anything related to just these permissions.

Comment: I can't say authoritatively, but I know of no way to do what you are attempting. I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not as a windows right or privilege.  That would typically be conferred as a container level permission, such as an OU, but you could also assign it higher.

Usually with this type of approach, you may find it is necessary to also confer the permission to manage user objects (allow ACE for read/write all attributes), and perhaps also restrict other activities, such as re-enabling disabled accounts (a deny ACE for the userAccountControl attribute on the Properties tab).

You will probably need to test this to ensure it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: I think he needs a local account (non-AD) solution